# Variável de $_Session não grava no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou usando mysqli e não consigo salva informação no banco de dados.  
Efetuei o teste com

```
echo var_dump($_SESSION); 
echo "<br />";
echo $_SESSION['login'];
```

O valor retornardo foi:  
array(2) { ["login"]=> string(6) "djalma" ["senha"]=> string(3) "123" }

```
    <?php
    session_start();

        require '../php/funcao_mysql.php';

    $cod_os = $_POST['N_OS'];
    $cod_usuario = $_SESSION['login']; 

    $sql = $con->prepare("insert into ControleOS (cod_os, cod_usuario, cod_cliente, NomeCliente, DataOs, Hora, DescProbl, Tp_Instalacao, MuCaboCliente,  
            MuCaboBackBone, MuRJ45, MuEmendaBargoa, MuTomada, MuBenjamimAdaptador, MuEsticadorCaboFE, MuRoldanaS, MuRoldanaD, MuAnel, MuFecho, 
            MuCaixaHermetica, MuBarraAterramento, MuTuboAterramento, MuAntena, MuRadio, TrPing, TrTracert, TrVelocidade, TrCaboCliente, TrPontoRede,
            TrRJ45, TrVerificPlacaRede, TrVerificDHCP, TrConfigDiscador, TrConfigRoteador, TrConfigRadio, TrHabilitacaoServico, TrInformacaoChuvas,
            TrTelefoneSuporte, TrMudancaPortaBackbone, TrMudancaPortaCliente, TrTreinamentoCliente )
                    Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )");
$sql->bind_param('iiissssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss', $cod_os, $cod_usuario, $cod_cliente, $NomeCliente, $DataOs, $Hora, $DescProbl, //7
                    $Tp_Instalacao, $MuCaboCliente, $MuCaboBackBone, $MuRJ45, $MuEmendaBargoa, $MuTomada, $MuBenjamimAdaptador, $MuEsticadorCaboFE,  //8
                    $MuRoldanaS, $MuRoldanaD, $MuAnel, $MuFecho, $MuCaixaHermetica, $MuBarraAterramento, $MuTuboAterramento, $MuAntena, $MuRadio, $TrPing, //10
                    $TrTracert, $TrVelocidade, $TrCaboCliente, $TrPontoRede, $TrRJ45, $TrVerificPlacaRede, $TrVerificDHCP, $TrConfigDiscador, //8
                    $TrConfigRoteador, $TrConfigRadio, $TrHabilitacaoServico, $TrInformacaoChuvas, $TrTelefoneSuporte, $TrMudancaPortaBackbone, //6
                    $TrMudancaPortaCliente, $TrTreinamentoCliente); //2
$sql->execute();
$sql->close();
?>
```

**Eu não coloquei todas as variáveis para resumir e pq o intuito desse post e passar $_Session para o Formulário e salvar no banco.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Atualização

Estava revendo um bloco de código e me lembrei de uma combinação de [**`http_build_query`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) e [**`parse_str`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) que pode ser útil para o seu caso.

```
$_SESSION['session.A'] = 'Meu valor para A';
$_SESSION['session.B'] = 'Meu valor para B';
$build = http_build_query( $_SESSION );
```

`$build` será uma sting com: *session.A=Meu+valor+para+A&session.B=Meu+valor+para+B*

```
parse_str( $build , $parse );
print_r( $parse );
```

`$parse` volta a ser um array: *array( 'session_A' => 'Meu valor para A' , 'session_B' => 'Meu valor para B')*

**<sub>* Nem queria atualizar, mas não deixa de ser uma forma. Embora possa obter o mesmo resultado, `json_encode` e `serialize` ainda são mais recomendadas.</sub>**

---

Você consegue gravar de duas maneiras, usando *json_encode* e *serialize*, veja abaixo:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = 'meu nome';
```

Usando *json_encode*

```
// output: {"name":"meu nome"}
$json = json_encode( $_SESSION );

// parâmetro TRUE retorna um array
// output: array( 'name' => 'meu nome' )
json_decode( $json , true );

// parâmetro stdClass retorna um onjeto stdClass
// output: stdClass Object $name -> 'meu nome'
json_decode( $json , false );
```

Usando *serialize*

```
// output: a:1:{s:4:"name";s:8:"meu nome";}
$serialize = serialize( $_SESSION );

// output: array( 'name' => 'meu nome' )
unserialize( $serialize );
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o serialize se você realmente necessita guardar isso do mesmo modo que recebe http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.serialize.php

Eu prefiro salvar isso em valor separado e recuperar posteriormente.

Comment: Você pode me mostrar como vc faria?

Comment: Discordo com o "Recomendar exclusão". A explicação é curta mas existe, a resposta não é um simples "Confira o {link}". @RenatoTavares, veja o guia [answer] para mais detalhes.

Comment: Concordo contigo, @brasofilo.
Obrigado.